# Python sympy : Using simplfy on boolean expression results with non simplified expression

Tags: python, boolean, sympy

I'm trying to simplify a boolean expression with `sympy` but I'm facing an issue:

```
from sympy.logic import simplify_logic,to_cnf,to_dnf
from sympy import Symbol,S

# Simplified to: 
#'deputy | mayor | (city & director) | (city & manager) | (director & investment & of)'
# Which seems as non simplifed expression
str(simplify_logic(eval('(city&manager)|(city&director)|(deputy)|(mayor)|(director&of&investment)')))
```

But this :

```
# Simplified to: 
# 'sales & (director | manager)'
# Which is simplified!
str(simplify_logic(eval('(sales&manager)|(sales&director)')))
```

How can I simplify the first expression?

Thank you!

EDIT : by simplifed I mean an expression with a minimum number of operators

PS: all words are defined as symbols:

```
for word in words:
    vars()[word]=Symbol(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

In light of the question, I guess you'd expect result such as:

```
'(city&(manager|director))|(deputy)|(mayor)|(director&of&investment)'
```

When delving into the `simplify_logic` function, we see the `form` parameter:

> string ('cnf' or 'dnf') or None (default).
> If 'cnf' or 'dnf', the simplest expression in the corresponding
> normal form is returned; if None, the answer is returned
> according to the form with fewest args (in CNF by default)

So, basically what happens is that the expression inputted is converted to either [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) form.

In our case, the expression is converted to DNF form, as it has fewer arguments.

Bouncing back to the start - the expression we'd expect is NOT a valid [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) or [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) form, so we won't get it.

Because DNF is an OR of ANDs, and sub-part expression `(city&(manager|director))` doesn't satisfy this (there is OR between `manager` and `director`).

However, the other expression is simplified to:

```
sales & (director | manager)
```

Because it's a valid [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) form.

**"Simplify" by minimizing boolean function**

Usually, simplification algorithms don't minimize the number of operands, rather than number of operators (logic gates), this usually means shorter-expression (doesn't necessarily - sometimes even longer).

These are a few algorithms used for boolean function minimization:

1. [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) (warning: it isn't suited for more than six input variables and practical only for up to four variables)
2. [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) (practical only for functions with a limited number of input variables and output functions)

The `sympy` provides an implementation in [`SOPform`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.SOPform) (smallest Sum of Products form) and [`POSform`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html#sympy.logic.boolalg.POSform) (smallest Product of Sums form).

3. [Espresso algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer#Espresso_algorithm)

And a tool [Espresso logic minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer), included in [pyeda](https://pypi.org/project/pyeda/):

Example usage of `espresso_exprs` function to minimize multiple expressions:

```
>>> f1 = Or(~a & ~b & ~c, ~a & ~b & c, a & ~b & c, a & b & c, a & b & ~c)
>>> f2 = Or(~a & ~b & c, a & ~b & c)
>>> f1m, f2m = espresso_exprs(f1, f2)
>>> f1m
Or(And(~a, ~b), And(a, b), And(~b, c))
>>> f2m
And(~b, c)
```

Comment: Why would `city` be pulled out rather than `director`? Either way it's not clear to me that that is a simplification.

Comment: I agree that there is ambiguity regarding the "simplified" according to OP. I've shown an example of such "simplified" form and later explained in detail why it's not simplified according to CNF or DNF. @OscarBenjamin

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there any way to transform my expression to its minimal form (fewest operators number) ?

Comment: Updated and elaborated in the post @octa_JS :)

Comment: I guess this is what sympy's `SOPform` and `POSform` functions are for: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html

Comment: Yes, they use the Quine–McCluskey algorithm, but the input representation is a bit different. I'll add this, thanks @OscarBenjamin

Comment: thank you for your very quick and helpful answers. How can I use SOP & POS form in my case ?

Comment: Welcome @octa_JS :) I'd refer you to the docs linked in the post, however, I must warn you beforehand both SOP & POS won't give you a result such as `'(city&(manager|director))|(deputy)|(mayor)|(director&of&investment)'` if that what you are looking for. (That expression is not a valid POS, SOP, CNF or either DNF form)